# Javascript/jQuery animate to dynamic height?

Tags: jquery, resize, jquery-animate, height

Does anyone know why this animates fine:

```
function setContainerHeight() {
    $(".pagecontainer").animate({
        height: '700px'
    }, 500);
}
```

i.e. a fixed height, but this doesn't animate at all?

```
function setContainerHeight() {
    $(".pagecontainer").animate({
        height: 'auto'
    }, 500);
}
```

It still resizes to auto, but no animation, just snaps to it.

My code:

JS:

```
<script>

    function setContainerHeight() {
        $(".pagecontainer").animate({
            height: 'auto'
        }, 500);
    }

    $('.link').on('click', function(e){
        $('.pagecontainer>div').fadeOut(0);
        setContainerHeight();
        $(this.getAttribute("href")).fadeIn();
    });

</script>
```

CSS:

```
.pagecontainer {
min-height:450px;
width:80%;
min-width:800px;
padding:50px 0;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.pagecontainer>div{
display: none; /*wait until page needs to be faded in*/
padding-left:50px;
padding-right:50px;
position:relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="pagecontainer">

    <a href="#page1" class="link">page 1</a>
    <a href="#page2" class="link">page 2</a>
    <a href="#page3" class="link">page 3</a>

    <div id="page1">TONS OF TEXT HERE</div>

    <div id="page2">A BIT OF TEXT HERE</div>

    <div id="page3">BUNCH OF IMAGES</div>

</div>
```

There are different divs fading in/out, each needing a different height. The width of the pages is also dynamic but doesn't need animation, just stretches/shrinks with viewport.

Thanks.

Comment: without reading the jquery code, I would guess animate won't know its end height. Fix is to find it then animate giving it the integer.

Answer (score 7):

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/zbB3Q/

Animate doesn't know the end height. You'll need to get it then animate, but to do that you have to quickly set the height and return to what it was before animating.

```
function setContainerHeight() {
    var heightnow=$(".pagecontainer").height();
    var heightfull=$(".pagecontainer").css({height:'auto'}).height();

    $(".pagecontainer").css({height:heightnow}).animate({
        height: heightfull
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Won't this trigger a FOUC (flash of un-styled content) when `var heightfull = $(".pagecontainer").css({height:'auto'}).height();` is read?

Comment: No it's too quick, this isn't like js waiting for body.onload after the browser has displayed some content.

Comment: I have edited my question to include my JS/CSS/HTML. .pagecontainer is the overall container, with several div pages inside it. The pages change so the .pagecontainer should change height to reflect it. I've tried your code by having `var targetpage = $(this).attr("href");` then getting the height of targetpage but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `var targetpage = $(this).attr("href");`? Then what are you doing with targetpage (which is a string)? Did you mean `var targetpage = $($(this).attr("href"));`

Answer (score 2):

From experience I had this same problem but you cannot animate to `auto`. However you can get the containers height before hand and then animate to that. For example.

```
function setContainerHeight() {
    newHeight = $('.pagecontainer').height();
    $(".pagecontainer").animate({
        height: newHeight
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: That won't change anything.

Comment: @popnoodles ah yes you're right it doesn't, thanks lesson learnt.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party here, but I had the exact same problem in some of my code.  I wrote a tiny jQuery plugin to resolve this - its available [here](https://github.com/azaslavsky/jQuery-Animate-Auto-Plugin) if you're still in need of a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little plugin that deals with this problem - should be fairly straightforward, based on Darcy Clarke's method which has been published [here](http://darcyclarke.me/development/fix-jquerys-animate-to-allow-auto-values-2/), with some (imo) very necessary improvements.  Just plug and play for jQuery:

https://github.com/azaslavsky/jQuery-Animate-Auto-Plugin