# How to adapt changing tabs JS to transition height on tab change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have some code in place that successfully changes some tabs on click. The issue I have is when the tab changes, if the content in the tab is different in height the content beneath jumps up and down on change.

I wondered if there is a way I can adapt my current setup to add some sort of a transition so that the content beneath slides up/down when the content above changes on click?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pvarqefh/1/)

```
$(".tab-content .group").hide(); // Initially hide all content
$(".tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
$(".tab-content .group:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content
$('.tabs li a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if ($(this).attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
     return       
   } else{             
     $(".tab-content .group").hide(); //Hide all content
     $(".tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
     $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
     $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [this question has already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393766/javascript-jquery-animate-to-dynamic-height). The idea is that you look at what the current height is and what the height would be if set to auto, and then you animate the difference. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/zbB3Q/

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    setContainerHeight();
});


function setContainerHeight() {
    var heightnow=$(".pagecontainer").height();
    var heightfull=$(".pagecontainer").css({height:'auto'}).height();

    $(".pagecontainer").css({height:heightnow}).animate({
        height: heightfull
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: How would I apply this to my current setup? Create a separate function that animates the height and call that function in the else part of my original click event?